# Apple maps URL scheme, how to use near parameter

Tags: ios, apple-maps

I am trying to search for say "Dominos" near my current location through Apple maps. But it shows results which are not at all near my location

At first i tried the following scheme
    @"http://maps.apple.com/map?ssll=%g,%g&q=Dominos",latitude,longitude

But it didn't worked out, so i am trying to utilize **near** parameter. How i am supposed to use this? I tried passing **lat,long**, but it just add up to search parameter on apple maps.

Same query works prefectly for google maps, but i wonder how it get it done for apple maps

Answer (score 0):

The near actually takes a city,state format. I'm not sure if it can use a lat/long.